LControlZoom Not Showing for Vue
I am using the vue3-leaflet library to display a simple map (it is almost the exact same as the example in the documentation)
<template>
  <!-- Map -->
  <LMap :zoom="14" :center="modelValue" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <!-- The Map Tile -->
    <LTileLayer url='https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' layer-type="base" name="OpenStreetMap"/>
    
    <!-- Add Zoom Control -->
    <LControlZoom position="bottomright" />
  </LMap> 
</template>

However, the Zoom Control is not showing on the map, and the Javascript console is showing this warning:

[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: LControlZoom If this is a
native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component
resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

What am I missing?  I thought the demo example would work out of the box...
EDIT:
For clarity, I've installed it using npm and have the necessary imports.  I can see the map and the tile layer, but not the zoom control

You also need to install it, depending on what you use: https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/quickstart/#installation

Sorry I didn't mention it.  I've installed it and I didn't add the imports/component definitions to my code snippet above.  I can see the Map and the tile layer...however the zoom control is the one thing not showing.
